# How i trigger another activity with certain condition?

Tags: java, android

How do I trigger an `Activity` (dialog) under certain conditions, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNqu8.png)?
For example, if the phone battery goes 15%, it should trigger an `Activity` (dialog) that would appear on top of other apps for a short period of time.
It's like giving a notification if the battery is low.
As for the notification, I'll make custom dialog `Activity`.

Comment: What do you mean by popup ? is it just another activity? or some dialog?

Comment: Please go through https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/toc-v2. You will get almost everything you want and beyond.

Comment: For this, you would need to "catch" the Intent that the system sends in these cases: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW . Add the IntentFilter in your Android Manifest

Comment: oh... thanks you the name what i looking for its call `Toast`